# Убрать пустое расстояние между слайдами

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Делаю что-то вроде вертикальной карусели, при прокрутке слайд, который "уезжает", сворачивается при помощи свойств css3.
HTML

```
<div id="scroll">
    <ul>
        <li style="background: red;"></li>
        <li style="background: green;"></li>
        <li style="background: yellow;"></li>
        <li style="background: blue;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scroll {


 position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slides-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: all 3000ms ease;
     -moz-transition: all 3000ms ease;
      -ms-transition: all 3000ms ease;
       -o-transition: all 3000ms ease;
          transition: all 3000ms ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.current {
  -webkit-transform: none;
          transform: none;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

.prev {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(900px) rotateX(80deg);
          transform: perspective(900px) rotateX(80deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.next {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(900px) rotateX(-80deg);
          transform: perspective(900px) rotateX(-80deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0 0px;
}

/* ------------ */

.scroll {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
}
```

jQuery

```
$.fn.customScroll = function () {
var $this = $(this);
var $list = $(this).find('ul');
var $lis = $list.find('li');
var count = $lis.length;
var direction,
currentSlidePosition;

$this.addClass('scroll');
$list.addClass('slides-list');
$lis.addClass('slide');
$lis.filter(':first').addClass('current');
$lis.filter(':not(:first)').addClass('next');

var scrollHeight = $lis.eq(0).height();

function gotoSlide(direction) {
    currentSlidePosition = $lis.filter('.current').index();

    if ((direction === 1 && currentSlidePosition === 0) || (direction === -1 && currentSlidePosition === count - 1)) {
        return;
    }

    $lis.removeClass('current');
    $lis.eq(currentSlidePosition - direction).removeClass('prev next').addClass('current');
    $lis.filter('.current').prevAll().addClass('prev');
    $lis.filter('.current').nextAll().addClass('next');

    $list.animate({
        scrollTop: (direction === -1) ? $list.scrollTop()+scrollHeight : $list.scrollTop()-scrollHeight
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        complete: function() {
        }
    });
}

$this.on('mouseenter', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if ($list.is(':animated')) {
            return;
        }

        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            direction = 1; //up
        } else {                
            direction = -1; //down
        }

        gotoSlide(direction);
    });
});
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#scroll').customScroll();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5unj2wu/7/
Но при этом получается пустое расстояние между уезжающим и новым слайдом. Не могу разобраться, как его можно убрать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий [пример](http://codepen.io/olegatro/pen/xGypyY).

Первая причина отступов была в том, что `transition` действует не только на `transform` но и на `transform-origin`. Поэтому требовалось явно указать какое свойство изменять - `transform`. Т.к. виновник отступов это `transform-origin`.

Вторая причина, что у класса `current` должен меняться `transform-origin` при движении скролла вниз или вверх. Иначе у Вас при движении вниз всё будет ок, но при движении вверх, отступ сохранится. Это всё из за того, что при указании значения `transform: none;` сброс происходит не сразу, на него действует `transition`. Поэтому тут два решения, либо динамически изменять `transform-origin` при движении вверх или вниз, либо просто сбрасывать `transition`. В примере выше, мы просто сбрасываем `transition` для класса `current`.